# magento 2 : замена копирайта в админке

Tags: php, magento

Хочу поменять копирайт в админке magento2.x, но переопределение не происходит.
Создал свой модуль app/code, указал зависимость от системного

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd"> 
      <module name="Weblips_Logo" setup_version="0.0.1"/> 
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
</config>
```

перенес `<MY>/view/adminhtml/templates/page/footer.phtml`
и заменил

```
<p class="magento-version">
    <strong><?php  echo 'MY-COPY'; ?></strong>
    <?php echo __('ver. %1', $block->getMagentoVersion()) ?>
</p>
```

`setup:upgrade` и `cache:flush` делал 
Результат - отображается также magento !!! Что я делаю не так ? Менять внутри Magento_Backend - НЕ ВАРИАНТ.

Comment: один вопрос. Зачем вам это?

Comment: Оригинальный вопрос. Затем, чтобы его изменить.

Answer (score 0):

Если не через `Magento_Backend`, тогда если есть возможность добавить в стиль `css`, который подгружается на любой странице в магенто выборку по `id` логотипа Magento, и установить ему `display: none !important;` (это же можно сделать через `js` скрипт, который подгружается на всех страницах в административной панели).

P.S. Этот очень кустарный метод достижения требуемого, но если нет других опций, то наверно самый простой.

P.S.S. Либо можно заменить логотип Magento, на свой в директории с файлами фреймворка/движка, найдя соответствующее изображение и заменив его на свое.